# have a function return it's results with each change react (using a pointer like affect in js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I come from a background of pointers and glory so this is something I'm having trouble understanding.

If I have a class in react:

```
import ComplexMathFunction from 'ComplexMathFunction.js';

export default class DisplayArray extends React.Component {
 constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
    gird : SomeGrid // someGrid is a 5 x 5 array
    }
 }
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (this.props.doMath !== prevProps.doMath) {
      this.AdjustGrid();
  }
 }
 AdjustGrid = () => {
 let tmpGrid = ComplexMathFunction(this.state.grid);
  this.setState({ grid: tmpGrid)}
 }
 render (
  return (
    // display the grid within state
  )
}
```

where `ComplexMathFunction` is nothing more than a loop that takes the value evaluates each grid element and offers a solution for each until the grid is complete.

The `DisplayArray`  detects if it has to call a math function, in which it does, how can I have it so within each loop of the math function I can return and set it to state? In my previous experience of programming, I could pass a pointer in which the function would change the value, in which case it would be rendered.

But that is not the case in javascript/react. I could house the entire `ComplexMathFunction` within this `DisplayGrid` but that seems like just bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You may try with `refs`:

```
class DisplayArray extends React.Component {
 AdjustGrid = () => {

 }
 render (
  return (
    // display the grid within state
  )
}

class Parent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return <div>
      <button onClick={() => this.displayArray.AdjustGrid()}>compute</button>
      <DisplayArray ref={d => this.displayArray = d}/>
    </div>
  }
}
```